# How to decode list of urls in file

Tags: python, perl, file

I have file which contain urls. Each urls is separated by new line. The contents of url is encoded format. I need to use vi command line to decode the content of each line.

List of urls is as follow:

`http://www.example.com/programm_detail.aspx?bu=%2fhome%2fprogramm_AbisZ.aspx%3fLang%3dde&amp;FilmId=22659&amp;Lang=de&amp;Search=
http://www.example.com/programm_detail.aspx?bu=%2fhome%2fprogramm_AbisZ.aspx%3fLang%3dde&amp;FilmId=22104&amp;Lang=de&amp;Search=
http://www.example.com/programm_detail.aspx?bu=%2fhome%2fprogramm_AbisZ.aspx%3fLang%3dde&amp;FilmId=21968&amp;Lang=de&amp;Search=`

Please let me know how to decode this content.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly iterate over the file and get each url. Use requests library to send requests and get the response. The following code works if you have installed the requests library and you put your urls in a file named 'inp' in the same directory that you run this code from.

```
   import requests

    with open('./inp') as f:
        for line in f:
            print repr(line)
            r = requests.get(line.strip())
            print r.text
```